# WPF Changing Image in Button Template

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to create a button template where the button image content changes. However, I get no image showing at all with the following code. What am I doing wrong? Setting the style directly in the Page xaml works fine.

```
<Style x:Key="NetworkConnectivity" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="120"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="120"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.7"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>

    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Width="50">
                    <Image.Style>
                        <Style>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding NetConfig}" Value="false">
                                    <Setter Property="Image.Source" Value="/images/Unconfigured.png"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding NetConfig}" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="Image.Source" Value="/images/Disconnected.png"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Image.Style>
                </Image>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Be aware that ContentTemplate and Template are different things.

Comment: Try binding the image outside (before) the triggers too. There are cases where you get this behavior when forgetting the default state. May be related to view inflation.

Answer (score 0):

Not the exact solution but an alternative. Below is a excerpt from my work that shows how to switch images for buttons based on triggers. Instead of style, I use a usercontrol which is reused. The data that are bound are dependency properties. You can use data trigger. In your case assign two images, make one collapsed and on trigger toggle collapse.

```
<UserControl x:Class="ParameterModule.Base.Controls.ButtonWImage"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ParameterModule.Base.Controls"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         x:Name="UctrlButtonWImage"
         d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="100">

<Button Click="Button_Click" CommandParameter="{Binding CommandParameter, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:ButtonWImage}}}" Command="{Binding Command, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:ButtonWImage}}}" Cursor="Hand" >
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <StackPanel>
                <Image x:Name="PrimaryImage" Source="{Binding PrimaryImage, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:ButtonWImage}}}" Visibility="Visible" Stretch="UniformToFill" StretchDirection="Both"/>
                    <Image x:Name="SecondaryImage" Source="{Binding HoverImage, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:ButtonWImage}}}" Visibility="Collapsed" Stretch="UniformToFill" StretchDirection="Both"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="PrimaryImage" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="SecondaryImage" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
</UserControl>
```